# How to parse this string into kv in awk in a simple way

Tags: awk

Now I have a str in awk like this:

```
str = "a='abc',b=1,c='http://xxxx,http://yyyy,http://zzz'"
```

How can I parse it to get this result:

```
(a abc)(b 1)(c http://xxxx,http://yyyy,http://zzz)
```

By now I still implement it in such an ugly way:

```
result = ""
while (match(str, /[^=]*=('[^']*'|[^,]*),/) != 0) {
    subs = substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH)
    str = substr(str, RSTART + RLENGTH, length(str) - RSTART - RLENGTH + 1)
    split(subs, vec, "=")
    gsub(/'/, "", vec[1])
    gsub(/'/, "", vec[2])
    if (substr(vec[2], length(vec[2]), 1) == ",") {
        vec[2] = substr(vec[2], 0, length(vec[2]) - 1)
    }
    result = result"("vec[1]" "vec[2]")"
}
```

I wonder if there exist some more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

### Using awk

The trick here is that we need to treat quoted commas differently from unquoted commas. That can be done as follows:

```
$ echo "$str" | awk -F"'" -v OFS="" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(",", ")(", $i)} {gsub("=", " "); print "("$0")"}' 
(a abc)(b 1)(c http://xxxx,http://yyyy,http://zzz)
```

#### How it works

- `-F"'" -v OFS=""`

  This sets the input field separator to a single quote and the output separator to an empty string.
- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(",", ")(", $i)}`

  This replaces unquoted commas (odd fields) with `)(`.

  Even numbered fields represent the *quoted* strings and they are left unchanged here.
- `gsub("=", " ")`

  This replaces equal signs with spaces.
- `print "("$0")"`

  This adds parens to the beginning and end and prints the line.

### Using sed

```
$ echo "$str" | sed -r ":a; s/^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^,']*),/\1\n/; ta; s/,/)(/g; s/^/(/; s/$/)/; s/\n/,/g; s/'//g; s/=/ /g" 
(a abc)(b 1)(c http://xxxx,http://yyyy,http://zzz)
```

#### How it works

First, remember that sed processes input line-by-line.  That means that, unless we put one in it, no line in sed's pattern space will contain a newline character.

This command works by replacing all *quoted* commas with newline characters.  It then adds `(` to the beginning of the line, `)` to the end of the line, and replaces the remaining commas with `)(`.  The newline characters are changed back to commas.  Next the single-quotes are removed. Finally, the `=` signs are then replaced with spaces and we are done.

We can tell whether a comma is quoted or unquoted by whether is it is preceded by an odd or an even number of single-quotes.

In more detail:

- `sed -r`

  This starts sed with extended regular expressions.
- `:a; s/^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^,']*),/\1\n/; ta`

  This converts all quoted commas into newline characters.  The regex `^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^,']*)` matches, starting at the beginning of the line, any odd numbers of single-quotes and the text surrounding them up to the first comma afterward.   The substitution command `s/^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*),/\1\n/` consequently replaces the first quoted comma found with a newline, `\n`.

  `:a` is a label.  `ta` is a test: it branches back to label `a` if a substitution was made.  Thus, as many substitutions are made as needed to replace all the quoted commas with newline characters.
- `s/,/)(/g; s/^/(/; s/$/)/`

  These three substitution commands puts parens everywhere that we want one.
- `s/\n/,/g`

  Now that we have parens where we need them, this converts the newline characters that we added back to commas.
- `s/'//g`

  This removes all the single quotes.
- `s/=/ /g`

  This replaces the equal signs with spaces.